Union between tabular model and SQL table with MDX in Analysis Service
I have this query extracted from a tabular model:
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Sales], [Measures].[Quantity Sold] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { 
            ([Invoice].[Number].[Number].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Period].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Sales Person].[Email].[Email].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Company].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Business Partner].[Business Partner].[Business Partner].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Business Partner].[Consolidated Partner].[Consolidated Partner].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Business Partner].[Card Code].[Card Code].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Invoice].[Type].[Type].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Item].[Group Base].[Group Base].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Invoice].[Webshop Id].[Webshop Id].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Invoice Rows].[Web Order Line Id].[Web Order Line Id].ALLMEMBERS *
            [Invoice Rows].[Line Number].[Line Number].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Item].[Boy Group Name].[Boy Group Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Item].[Product Group Name].[Product Group Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Item].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [Business Partner].[SSP Region Code].[SSP Region Code].ALLMEMBERS *
            [Business Partner].[Country].[Country].ALLMEMBERS ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Reporting Currency].[Selection].&[2] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( { [Invoice].[Type].&[1], [Invoice].[Type].&[0] } ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( {[Company].[Name].&[beas group ag.], 
[Company].[Name].&[Boyum IT Inc.],
[Company].[Name].&[Boyum IT Solutions A/S], 
[Company].[Name].&[Boyum IT Solutions GmbH], 
[Company].[Name].&[Boyum IT Solutions Spain S.L], 
[Company].[Name].&[Boyum IT Solutions Shanghai Co., Ltd.], 
[Company].[Name].&[Boyum IT Solutions Hungary Kft.], 
[Company].[Name].&[Produmex Americas Inc], 
[Company].[Name].&[Paperflow ApS], 
[Company].[Name].&[Perfion A/S], 
[Company].[Name].&[Paperflow Service Center Bulgaria Ltd.],
[Company].[Name].&[Boyum IT Solutions BVBA]} ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Sales]))) 
WHERE ( [Reporting Currency].[Selection].&[2] ) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS

I would like to make a Union with a SQL table coming from the same datasource.

SELECT  [Number]
,[Date]
,[Email]
,[Name]
,[BusinessPartner]
,[ConsolidatedPartner]
,[CardCode]       ,[Type]
,[GroupBase]
,[WebshopId]
,[WebOrderLineId]
,[LineNumber]
,[BoyGroupName]
,[ProductGroupName]
,[ItemName]
,[SSPRegionCode]
,[Country]
,[Sales]
,[QuantitySold]   FROM [TARGIT BIA for SAP Business One].[dbo].[FactProformaNetronic]

My question is: is it possible to do it with MDX? Or should I bring the table into the tabular model(Cube) before union it?
Thank you!
